# How to check whether user already likes a page or not using FB.api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page, fbml

I have used below code to check whether the user already likes the page or not.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
               FB.init({
                appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
                channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                oauth: true,
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response && response.authResponse) {
         getAPIResponse();
      }
      else {
          FB.login(function (response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                   getAPIResponse();
              }
              else {
                document.getElementById('MainView').style.display = 'none';
                   }
          });
                }
            });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
   (function (d) {
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

 function getAPIResponse() {
         FB.api("me/likes/XXXXXXXXXXXXX", function (response) {
                if (response.data.length == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('MainView').style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('MainView').style.display = 'none';
                    alert("Like our Page to show Calendar");
                }
            });
  }
```

The above code previously working correctly. But now response.data.length is always returning zero. How to resolve above mentioned issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're not requesting the `user_likes` permission which is necessary to use the like info.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes

Furthermore, from your code example, you seem to "like-gate" content, which is not allowed by Facebook, and therefore will probably not allow you to pass the Login Review, which is necessary to use `user_likes`.

Comment: Is it necessary to submit my app for Login review approval from Facebook to access user_likes info ?

Comment: Yes, please have a look at the docs, those questions then mostly answer themselves: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Whether this review process is been implemented recently or from the beginning onward because this coding was working previously?

Comment: Can i use below v2.0 in my code to get my code work as previously window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
                    channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Channel File
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    oauth: true,
                    version: 'v1.X',
                    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
                });

Comment: No, v1.0 is gone since May 1st 2015: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation